# Compiling C++ Library that uses OpenCV Libraries without distributing OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I should preface this with saying I am very new to the C++ compilation process - and CMake - so any information would be appreciated.

I'm attempting to compile a program I've written as a shared library (.dll for Windows), that uses OpenCV Libraries. As such, I've compiled OpenCV as a collection of static libraries (.lib), added the build folder path as an environment variable (and updated path), and added it to the Additional Include Directories in Visual Studio.

However, it's my understanding that since I'm compiling to a dynamic link library, the OpenCV .lib files would need to be shipped with it.

Is there any way to package the OpenCV libraries WITH my library, without packaging the entirety of the OpenCV source code?

My current CMakeLists.txt is as follows if it helps at all:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

PROJECT(MySharedLibrary DESCRIPTION "My Shared Library") 

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBS})

include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

file(GLOB all_FILES
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp"
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/program.cpp"
)

###### LIBRARY COMPILATION ######
add_library(MySharedLibrary SHARED ${all_FILES})
target_link_libraries(MySharedLibrary ${OpenCV_LIBS} "-static")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without being specific to OpenCV:

- If you link a static library into a DLL, you don't need to distribute the static library with the DLL.
- If you link a static library that depends on another static library, you need to distribute both static libraries.

The former point will depend on the API in the DLL. If the API uses classes that are in the static library and not exported by the DLL, the calling module might need the static library to link those classes.